# CSS Grid: Change the direction of a row? And is it possible for child element to indent by 1/-1 column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

This question is in two parts as I venture into playing around with CSS Grid...

_

**1. Can you flip a CSS Grid item (row) like your would with the direction in Flex?**

I have a grid/row that is main up for 2 side-by-side divs. I know I could use `flex` for this in another use case but here I need to use CSS Grid. Every alternating row will be flipped so the image is on the other side. Without flex, can I achieve this with CSS Grid?

I thought I could specify which columns each block should start at, which did move the position to the correct place. The problem was all the content was squashed into a very narrow column.

**Example:** https://codepen.io/moy/pen/QWpMjKe

I thought a hack could be to use `direction: rtl` on the parent, then switch the direction back of all the child elements - but that seems a bit messy and probably frowned upon?

_

**2. Can a child element also follow the same grid?**

As you can see I have a negative margin of `-25%` on the title so it overlays the image. I was wondering is it possible for that element to align to the grid more precise? So it would essentially be minus 1 (or 2) columns in the parent grid?

Though I suppose this would probably make the clipping difficult/impossible?

Thanks in advance - look forward to getting some guidance!

**EDIT**
I made some progress with flipping the columns using `grid-column` but that caused the vertical alignment to break and stack the two elements. But I thought I'd post this as I was lacking a code snippet before...

```
.grid__item--flipped {
    //direction: rtl;
    
    .grid__item--image,
    .grid__item--caption {
        //direction: ltr;
    }
    
    .grid__item--image {
        grid-column: 7 / 13;            
    }
    
    .grid__item--caption {
        grid-column: 1 / 7;
    }
}
```

Comment: you also could use `grid-area` or use `nth-rule` to switch the row or column of all child elements.

Answer (score 1):

As said by tacoshy in the comments, you can use a nth-rule:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
    grid-auto-rows: 50px 50px;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.element:nth-child(4n + 3) {
    grid-column: 2;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">Element</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
    <div class="element">Element2</div>
    <div class="image">Image2</div>
    <div class="element">Element3</div>
    <div class="image">Image3</div>
    <div class="element">Element4</div>
    <div class="image">Image4</div>
    <div class="element">Element</div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for as well!